# Eclipse keep asking about SVN credentials

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have tried to move SVN project to Git.
I have created a remote REPO and pushed my project there.
Whenever I open Eclipse Europa I keep getting a message about SVN credentials and I can't get rid of it; after the Cancel button is pressed, the same window appear again.

**How to get rig of the nasty window?**

[image]

I have deleted hidden .svn folders and tried steps suggested in this article:
http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/ide/eclipse/fix-eclipse-svn-always-asking-for-login-and-password-clear-keyring-or-cache

Comment: Are some projects still shared via SVN (right-click project _Team > Disconnect)? Are you sure, you are using Eclipse Europa which is more than 10 years old? Do you use Subversive or Subclipse?

Comment: @howlger, yes I'm positive which version of Eclipse I'm using. Unfortunately, I have to. I'm using neither Subversive nor Subclipse.
And I can't check whether some projects still shared via SVN as I can't close this window

Comment: What prevents you from updating Eclipse? (Eclipse does not support SVN out of the box. You have as Eclipse SVN team provider either [_Subclipse_](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subclipse) or [_Subversive_](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subversive-svn-team-provider).)

Comment: @howlger clients restrictions. Subclipse is installed as the plug-in

Comment: That sound similar: http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/ide/eclipse/fix-eclipse-svn-always-asking-for-login-and-password-clear-keyring-or-cache

Comment: @howlger unfortunatelly, that didn't help

Comment: If there are hidden `.svn` folders somewhere in your project folders, delete them.

Comment: @howlger didn't work

Comment: What do you mean by _"that didn't help"_ and _"didn't work"_? Please complete your question for more information and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @howlger I have followed the steps in the article and have deleted .svn folders; keep getting the nasty window

Comment: If you create a new workspace and import your project(s) into the new workspace, is the dialog still displayed?

Comment: @howlger the problem is gone. Post your answer below. I will mark as the correct one for this question. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new workspace (e. g. by using the [command line argument `-data`](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html)) and import your project(s) from the old into the new workspace.